# Django model design - 1 or multiple tables

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django app where the user can add various activities. Some activities have fields that are only applicable to itself.

Option 1 (multiple tables) seems cleaner in some aspects, but I want to show all the activities in a listview, which makes option 2 more attractive. I'll also have a model form where they add a particular activity.

Is one of the options clearly better than the other or is it a matter of preference?

**Option 1**:

```
class BaseActivity(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    ave_heart_rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TennisActivity(BaseActivity):
    pass # no extra fields

class GolfActivity(BaseActivity):    
    score = models.IntegerField() #only applicable to golf

class JogActivity(BaseActivity):    
    distance = models.FloatField() #only applicable to jogging
```

**Or option 2**:

```
class BaseActivity(models.Model):    
    activity_choices = (('Tennis', 'tennis'),
                        ('Golf','golf'),
                        ('Jog','jog'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity_type = models.Charfield(choices=activity_choices)
    date = models.DateField()
    ave_heart_rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    distance = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on how extensible you want it to be. If you do it the first way you can add new activities without worrying about updating the entire DB. It would make the logic behind inputting and dealing slightly harder, but not that much. Option 2 would mean harder to extend, but if you aren't worried about that it's a much easier way of dealing with it overall.

I would personally choose option 1.